# JTable cell not editable but clickable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, clickable

I want to put an action whenever someone clicks a cell. open another gui for example. But how do i make a cell clickable BUT not editable? These are results for an sql query. I can't manage to make the table uneditable though. Do I need a listener or something? and if yes where should I put it?

Here is my code:

```
public class AllResultsFromDB extends JFrame
{

    GUI ins = new GUI();

    public AllResultsFromDB(GUI x)
    {
        Vector columnNames = new Vector();

        Vector data = new Vector();
        this.ins = x;

        try
        {   
            // Initializing GUI class in order to call getSelectedTable() method.
//            GUI ins = new GUI();
            //System.out.println(ins.getSelectedTable());
            Login sgui = new Login();

            String dburl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL";
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection( dburl, sgui.getUsername(), sgui.getPassword() );


            //  Fetch data from table specified by user

            String query = "SELECT * FROM "  + ins.getSelectedTable() + " ORDER BY id";
            System.out.println(query);
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);   
            ResultSetMetaData metad = rset.getMetaData();
            int columns = metad.getColumnCount();



            //  This loop gets the names of the columns

            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
            {
                columnNames.addElement( metad.getColumnName(i) );
                //columnNames.addElement("PROFILES");
            }




            //  This loop gets the data inside the rows

            while (rset.next())
            {
                Vector row = new Vector(columns);

                //Vector b = new Vector((Collection)button);

                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
                {
                    row.addElement( rset.getObject(i) );
                }

                data.addElement( row );
                //data.addElement(b);
            }

            rset.close();
            stmt.close();
            connection.close();




            //  Create table with results

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames)
        { 

            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            { 
                for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
                {
                    Object obj = getValueAt(row, column);


                    if (obj != null)
                    {
                        return obj.getClass();
                    }
                }

                return Object.class;
            }

        };


        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scroll );
        //table.addMouseListener(l);
        //table.setEnabled(false);
        //table.setDragEnabled(true);



        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add( panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Start by taking a look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

The `isCellEditable` method the `TableModel` determines of a cell is editable or not.  This method should return `false`

When you supply column/data information to the `JTable` directly, the `JTable` creates a `DefaultTableModel` internally.  This class's `isCellEditiable` method will return `true` by default.

By using something like `DefaultTableModel`, you can override this method without with to much trouble and set the model to the table directly.

Next, you need to attach a `MouseListener` to the table

Take a look at [How to write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

You can then use [getSelectedColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedColumn%28%29), [getSelectedRow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRow%28%29) to get the selected cell.

You'll also need to use [convertRowIndexToModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel%28int%29) and [convertColumnIndexToModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToModel%28int%29) to convert between the view and model indices

Comment: The key thing for OP to understand, I think, is that they have to provide a `TableModel` to the JTable instead of just constructing it using the data directly. A `new DefaultTableModel(){...}` with `isCellEditable()` overwritten should do the trick.

Comment: It might not have being highlighted enough - *"By using something like DefaultTableModel, you can override this method without with to much trouble"*...

Comment: Yeah, I caught that part, which is why I commented instead of adding a new answer. I might not have been clear enough myself; I meant that a newcomer might not quite understand _how_ or _where_ to "use something like a `DefaultTableModel`" - the emphasis in my comment should've been "_provide a `TableModel` to the `JTable`..._" That said, the tutorials you posted should hopefully do the trick.

Comment: I agree with your comment and feedback, hopefully the updated answer provides a little more information