# table.getSelectedRow() doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rows, selected

Can somebody tell me why this doesn't work? The line `System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow());` is red for some reason! I want each time I click a row to show me which row is selected. Am I missing something here?

```
            table = new JTable(data, columnNames) {


                public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                    for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++) {
                        Object obj = getValueAt(row, column);


                        if (obj != null) {
                            return obj.getClass();
                        }
                    }

                    return Object.class;
                }


            };


        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(scroll);


        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);



        table.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow());

            }

        });
```

Comment: make table final @See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29#Final_variables

Comment: THANK YOU!! but can you explain me why is that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on what @BlackBox said, `table` isn't a class variable, but the mouse listener you've added is technically a new inner class. That new class doesn't have access to the `table` variable unless it is marked as `final` or unless the class that contains both `table` and the mouse listener has a reference to `table`.

Comment: ok I got it! thank you everyone! i have one final question though. How can it listen for DOUBLE clicking?

Comment: `if(e.getClickCount()==2){...}` inside your `mousePressed(MouseEvent e)` method.

Comment: Thanks again... seems though that when I am double clicking the cell goes in editing mode. any way of removing that?

Comment: This does not exist. There is setEnabled() but that makes the table unclickable also...

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that; I had a brain glitch and was hoping to get that deleted before you saw it. You'll need to read up on `TableModel`s - in a nutshell, the model you provide the table with should be returning `false` for its `isCellEditable(int row, int col)` method.

Comment: Well I've put it here:

            `final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames) {
                


                public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                    
                    for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++) {
                        
                        table.isCellEditable(row, column);
                        
                        Object obj = getValueAt(row, column);`

Says table might not have been initialized. Anyway thank you for your patience!

Comment: No problem. Since this has gone beyond the scope of the original question, feel free to post a new one (or browse the site or Oracle's JTable tutorials) if you're still having problems.

Comment: Actually I have posted it. it is here but I couldn't get any narrow answer. Please check it if it is not too much trouble.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114192/jtable-cell-not-editable-but-clickable?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Declare the table variable as `final`.

For more information, see `Final and inner classes` on this wiki page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29#Final_variables

Essentially, marking a variable as final tells the compiler the value will never change. This indication allows the compiler to capture and store values for inner classes it otherwise wouldn't have been able to do at run time.